# retrieve the status of a backgrounded lftp session

Tags: linux, script, ftp

I have an ongoing ftp upload with lftp which is backgrounded and i am wondering if there is a method to retrieve the status of the upload in a scripted way.

What i've figured out so far is a way to retrieve the status manually by attaching to the lftp session and typing 'jobs', f.eks:

```
lftp -c attach PID_OF_LFTP_PROCESS
```

then the lftp shell is prompting and i can type 'jobs'

```
[PID_OF_LFTP_PROCESS] Attached to terminal.
lftp foo@ftp.bar:/> jobs
```

output is something like:

```
[1] mput -c /mnt/media/upload/parts/testfiles.part* 
'/mnt/media/upload/parts/testfiles.part10.rar' at 124930848 (61%) 105.5K/s eta:12m [Sending data]
```

that is the output i need, but how can i retrieve it within a script?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?